# Group by the union of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can `GROUP BY` based on the union of two columns be achieved performantly? There may be `NULL` values in either column. Something like (obviously this doesn't work):

```
SELECT a.val, b.val
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id
GROUP BY UNION(a.val, b.val)
```

With results like:

```
a.val | b.val
-----------
1        1
2        2
NULL     3
4        NULL
5        5
```

Thanks!

Comment: `group by a.val, b.val`?

Comment: You also need an aggregate function (SUM, COUNT, etc) in the SELECT

Comment: @Nenos: no, not necessarily. It's essentially the same as `select distinct a.val, b.val from ...`

Comment: Try using `COALESCE` in both your `SELECT` and your `GROUP BY`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: ok, good to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use NVL

```
SELECT NVL(a.val, b.val)  FROM a LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id 
GROUP BY NVL(a.val, b.val)
```